# Match several file types in TkInter's file dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a GUI with TkInter.
I ask a path to the user through `tkinter.filedialog`, and I want to match `.png`, `.bmp` and `.jpg` files all three as `image files`, using a single pattern.

I tried with the following pattern, but it seems that the parentheses and the vertical bar are not considered as meta-characters, but rather as raw characters.
Therefore, neither of the three extensions are matched.

```
path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(
    title="Loading image from...",
    filetypes=(
        ("image files", "*.(png|bmp|jpg)"),
        ("all files", "*.*")))
```

What is the syntax to match several extensions with a single pattern?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think you can only match a single Windows-style-glob with each pattern—but you can pass a tuple of pattern. Let me do a quick search…

Comment: @abarnert: you can pass a tuple.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, I found the confirmation in a dup of this question, which is why I closed it as a dup.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, I hadn't come across that dup.

Comment: For future reference: There are many tkinter behaviors that are not documented, or only documented in a third-party site that's impossible to search for because of dozens of useless crapsites like pythonspot—but [the underlying Tcl/Tk docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm#M15) are always thorough. You do have to figure out how to map that Tcl stuff to what tkinter does in Python, but in this case, you could probably guess at and test at least passing separate filetypes with the same names.